# Optimization of Complex Functions, No Use?

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, complex-numbers

During reading the appendix to an engineering text, I came across the following remark:

"Complex cost functions are of no interest, because in the field of complex numbers 
no ordering (relations < and >) is defined and thus minimization or maximization 
makes no sense."

Anyone care to explain this observation, why does minimization not make sense in complex domain?

Comment: What could "minimum" possibly mean if there is no "<"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a function $f\colon: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ and you want to minimize this function. Then you have to find an argument $x$ such that $f(x)$ is minimal which means that $f(x) \leq f(y)$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$. The problem is that $\mathbb{C}$ does not have a natural ordering like $\mathbb{R}$. If you have two complex numbers $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$, you can not say that $a \leq b$ or $b \leq a$.

Of course, you can minimize the absolute value $|f(x)|$ but this might be not that what you want and this is also not a complex valued function any more.